# html + php что это такое?

Tags: php, html, css, вёрстка

Возможно вопрос глупый но тем не менее. Как то давно услышал где то на просторах интернета такую фразу:"сверстать страничку на php". Позже видел html файлы с расширением .php со структурой html но и так же добавленными php командами. Поискав вроде как нашел что это называется "изолированием от html" но так и не понял для чего это нужно. Всегда считал что php в web-разработке существует только на бэкенде а тут оказывается что и при верстке он используется. Разъясните пожалуйста новичку эту тему. Стоит ли фронтенд-разработчику углубляться в эту тему? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ну php можно использовать например в мультилендингах.
Чтоб при переходе по определенной UTM метке лендинг подстраивался под неё. Типа купить кондер LG или купить кондер samsung и в зависимости от этого лендинг будет выводить картинки lg\samsung и т.п.

Один из вариантов

Comment: php-код на бэкенде генерирует html-код и отдаёт клиенту, всё очень просто. Только вот php в любом случае ужасен и не надо в него углубляться вообще никак

Comment: @andreymal, чем же он настолько ужасен?)

Comment: @andreymal  php же специально создан был для вэб ... это вот когда другие технологии подстраивают под вэб вот это ужасно на самом деле

Comment: @МаксимЛенский это не мешает ему быть ужасным даже в сравнении с «подстроенными» технологиями

Comment: @andreymal  чем же он ужасный ? давайте не будем халиварить на stack это не очень хорошо... я за php а вы нет ... вот и всё